# Error compiling the new_op tutorial (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, tensorflow, new-operator

I would like to learn how to [install new op](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#adding-a-new-op). So for doing that i' m following the given tutorial. I made a folder named user_ops,  create a "zero_out.cc" file and copy the code given in the tutorial. When i' m trying to compile the Op into a dynamic library with g++ errors appear:

> zero_out.cc: In lambda function:
>   zero_out.cc:10:14: error: ‘Status’ has not been declared
>          return Status::OK();
>                 ^
>   zero_out.cc: At global scope:
>   zero_out.cc:11:6: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘’ to ‘tensorflow::Status (*)(tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext*)’ [-fpermissive]
>        });
>         ^
>   zero_out.cc:8:70: note: candidate is: ::operator void (*)(tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext*)() const 
>        .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
>                                                                         ^
>   zero_out.cc:8:70: note:   no known conversion from ‘void (*)(tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext*)’ to ‘tensorflow::Status (*)(tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext*)’
>   In file included from zero_out.cc:1:0:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:252:30: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘tensorflow::register_op::OpDefBuilderWrapper& tensorflow::register_op::OpDefBuilderWrapper::SetShapeFn(tensorflow::Status (*)(tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext*))’
>      OpDefBuilderWrapper& SetShapeFn(<

Why is that happening? How could i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your only problem is the undefined `Status` type -- and copying and pasting the tutorial code works just fine except for this -- you need to either move the `using namespace tensorflow` to before the first use of  `Status`, or fully qualify it (as in `return tensorflow::Status::OK()`)

For example, the `REGISTER_OP` section could read as follows, if you did the templated version:

```
REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Attr("T: {float, int32}")
    .Input("to_zero: T")
    .Output("zeroed: T")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return tensorflow::Status::OK();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that the Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) doesn't have the right code. 
So i followed the code of this [tutorial](http://tensorflow.classcat.com/2016/03/04/tensorflow-how-to-adding-a-new-op/) and it is working perfectly!
I have no clue what it says!